# Are JSFiddle fiddles permanent?

Tags: discussion, third-party

If a user posts a fiddle as their block of code, will this code be permanent enough in that we should allow that as the only code on the question?  I am sure that this has happened a couple of times.

Are other similar sites permanent as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those questions would be off topic. We cannot depend on external sites to make a question useful.

From the [help topic on asking:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)(emphasis added)

> To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> 1. Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, ***not a link to it***)

JSFiddle is useful for demoing and testing code, but links cannot make a question on topic. The question must be able to stand on its own.

Comment: so you are saying that the post should be on topic and Make Sense without the Fiddle, Correct?

Comment: Yes. We cannot depend on external sites to make a question useful. The question must be able to stand on its own.

Comment: would you please add that to your answer?  I think that is a big part of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. We can't generalize about all fiddles, since they are not all run by the same entity.
2. Nothing lasts forever.
3. Despite the best intentions, situations change.  A fiddle site could go dead due to cash flow reasons, or for a stupid mistake such as accidentally letting a domain registration lapse.

However, permanence of the link is not the only consideration.  A bigger issue is that Stack Exchange aims to build a Creative Commons-licensed body of knowledge, similar to Wikipedia.  By submitting content to this site, you automatically contribute to the [data dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/).

Why is the data dump important?  It's the community's insurance against Stack Exchange going dead or going rogue.  Should Stack Exchange decide to put our good-faith contributions behind a paywall, for example, someone could theoretically clone the site based on the data dump.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the General consensus is that,

**if the Question doesn't make sense without the Fiddle then we should**

- Ask the OP to post the relevant code

(*screenshots can supplement relevant code to show visually what the code does.*)

**AND/OR**

- Vote to close

so a Fiddle should be treated just like any other link (other than SE Site Links)

there is already a design in place that keeps someone from posting a JSFiddle link without code to go with it.

I think we need to be on alert about this issue though, to keep it consistent.

Comment: Pretty please, no code screenshots.

Comment: I added a little bit to that portion of my answer

Comment: I don't think the word "or" is appropriate there -- screenshots of the output are no substitute for the code.  They may be useful in addition to the code.

Comment: @BenVoigt I changed the verbage on the answer.